# Need Windows Monitor drivers for Sceptre X322BV-SRD

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, tv

I recently replaced my dead `Sceptre X325BV-FMDR` with a replacement, `Sceptre X322BV-SRR`, however, all that seems to be available monitor driver wise is the `Generic PnP Monitor`. It is functional, but entirely unacceptable for more advanced PC experience, never mind gaming, etc. The `X325` was plenty fine as a PC monitor, that is before it up and died, so it is not the "video card" that is the issue, I can promise you. I run both over `HDMI`. Can anyone suggest a decent monitor driver for it? Or am I just SOL with this particular unit? Disappointing would be a understatement of the year, I think. Hoping for a better driver, at any rate. Thanks for your responses. Drivers wise, I need a Windows 7 x64 driver, if possible. An x86 driver might work, but I would be hesitant to risk it.

Comment: That is a TV, not a monitor, so there will be no drivers available.

Comment: How, then, was I able for the `Sceptre X325BV-FMDR` to function well as a monitor? And I do mean, far and away better than a `Generic PnP Monitor`.

Comment: I was in a similar situation and contacted Sceptre for a driver. They told me there aren't any, and that "generic' was actually better than installing a driver. So if you just have to install a driver, don't buy Sceptre.  I suspect your previous monitor didn't have a driver either.

Comment: Actually, the previous TV/monitor was in fact recognized by Windows 7, believe it or not. And it actually carried me for a number of months, in fact, years. I was quite happy with it, until it died on a sudden, that is. If I can have identified even a satisfactory substitute that opens up the display, resolution, etc, that would be great.

Comment: TV's can be used as Monitors but they are still TV's.

Comment: @Moab Unhelpful. Something we already know, yes. Sometimes they also have the appropriate Windows drivers in order to experience the kind of HR experience I would expect from an HDMI device.

Comment: There is no help for your problem, there are No drivers available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, it is a non-issue today. My TV died completely, would not turn on this morning. Last night I experienced a rash of failures, the TV cycling power, perhaps several dozen times. And this morning would not turn on at all. Have not cracked the casing at all, but most likely something like blown capacitors, something along these lines, is the culprit. Such a shoddy experience with these folks, would recommend steering clear of `Sceptre`. That old adage, *you get what you pay for*, really does hold true, and they are cheap. I expect a lot more mileage out of it than the couple of days, literally, that I operated with the unit. That's just unacceptable at any level.